# How to interpret tkprof_table.ticks?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I googled on web trying to search the meaning of tkprof_table.ticks but I could not find anything.

Can someone help me understand what ticks column means?

The following ticks show a large value. It is certainly not the sum of all other columns. far far from close.

```
SELECT parse_cnt,parse_elap,exe_count, exe_cpu, exe_elap,fetch_elap,ticks, sql_statement
  FROM tkprof_table
 WHERE Lower(sql_statement) LIKE '%set transaction isolation level%'
 ORDER BY ticks desc



PARSE_CNT PARSE_ELAP EXE_COUNT EXE_CPU EXE_ELAP FETCH_ELAP      TICKS SQL_STATEMENT                                  
       10       1619        11   31250   164191          0 4294192015 set transaction isolation level serializable
       10       1619        11   31250   164191          0 4294192015 set transaction isolation level serializable
        1        102         1       0       59        696     355707 set transaction isolation level serializable
        1        125         2       0    31984          0      87975 set transaction isolation level serializable
        1        125         2       0    31984          0      87975 set transaction isolation level serializable
```

Thanks,

Update
I just ran

```
tkprof main.trc tkprof.txt insert=tkprof.sql record=Allsql.sql
```

The ticks column is in the tkprof_table that is generated in tkprof.sql

```
CREATE TABLE  tkprof_table
(
 date_of_insert                       DATE   
,cursor_num                           NUMBER 
,depth                                NUMBER 
,user_id                              NUMBER 
,parse_cnt                            NUMBER 
,parse_cpu                            NUMBER 
,parse_elap                           NUMBER 
,parse_disk                           NUMBER 
,parse_query                          NUMBER 
,parse_current                        NUMBER 
,parse_miss                           NUMBER 
,exe_count                            NUMBER 
,exe_cpu                              NUMBER 
,exe_elap                             NUMBER 
,exe_disk                             NUMBER 
,exe_query                            NUMBER 
,exe_current                          NUMBER 
,exe_miss                             NUMBER 
,exe_rows                             NUMBER 
,fetch_count                          NUMBER 
,fetch_cpu                            NUMBER 
,fetch_elap                           NUMBER 
,fetch_disk                           NUMBER 
,fetch_query                          NUMBER 
,fetch_current                        NUMBER 
,fetch_rows                           NUMBER 
,ticks                                NUMBER 
,sql_statement                        LONG 
);
set sqlterminator off
```

I did define ticsk.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it should refer to "clock ticks". The specific meaning will depend on how you populated the `tkprof_table` and probably how you set the `TICK` attribute when collecting statistics. Under common usage, you can probably assume that one `TICK` equals 10 ms.

Comment: I didn't define ticks. This column is generated by tkprof, I know it is measure in microssencond. What I am asking is the meaning, what is it measured for?, cpu? io, elapsed? or combined?